# Is there a word for nut, berry, & seed bars?

Tags: single-word-requests, food

Bars without oats, but rather only nuts dried berries and other seeds are increasingly common nowadays, but is there a word for them? 
If not in English, then maybe there is a word that could be borrowed?

Sample sentence: these aren't granola bars since they don't have grains in them; they are BLANK.

Comment: ... Just bird food...?

Comment: I eat these things sometimes and I don't think there's a standard name, based on what the packets say

Comment: Maybe we can come up with a name for them like 'Stuffed Bars' or anything else, that suits better.

Answer (score 1):

[According to a list of food network recipes, they use various names including:](http://www.foodnetwork.com/healthy/packages/healthy-every-week/quick-and-simple/make-your-own-snack-bars) snack bar, protein bar, and energy bar.

And the last one I saw was breakfast bar [from this BBC recipe.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/breakfast_bars_49065)

Here are a list of names for products that already exist.

[KIND Bars](https://www.kindsnacks.com/products/kind-nut-bars)
[KIND Breakfast Bars](https://www.kindsnacks.com/products/breakfast)
[Probar Energy Bars](http://shop.theprobar.com/Products/PROBAR-Fuel)
[Rise Protein Bars](https://risebar.com/)
[Larabar Fruit and Nut Bars](http://www.larabar.com/our-products/larabar)
[Larabar Nut and Seed Bars](http://www.larabar.com/our-products/larabar-nut-seed)
[Raw Revolution Fruit, Nut & Seed Super Food Bar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00II0Y7TY)
[Health Warrior Chia Bar](https://www.healthwarrior.com/)

As you can see from this list, it is also popular to call the bar something more specific based on what exactly is inside the bar (fruits, nuts, seeds, etc).

Comment: "Energy bars", I call them.